# Images in astro3.0 not found

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I have a basic astro project with the following structure:

```
└── src
    ├── assets
    │   └── images
    │       └── blend.webp
    ├── components
    │   └── CoffeeCard.astro
    ├── content
    │   ├── coffees
    │   │   └── blend.md
    │   └── config.ts
    ├── pages
    │   └── index.astro
    └── utils.ts
```

My blend.md references the image as:

```
image_src: "../../assets/images/blend.webp"
```

My config.ts configures the image as:

```js
// 1. Import utilities from `astro:content`
import { z, defineCollection } from 'astro:content';
// 2. Define your collection(s)
const coffeeCollection = defineCollection({
  schema: ({ image }) => z.object({
    origin: z.string(),
    title: z.string(),
    price: z.number(),
    image_src: image(),
    image_alt: z.string(),
  }),
});
// 3. Export a single `collections` object to register your collection(s)
//    This key should match your collection directory name in "src/content"
export const collections = {
  'coffee': coffeeCollection,
};
```

And when I try to render the image in the CoffeeCard.astro I do the following:

```
 <Image src={import(image_src)} alt={image_alt} height={540} width={550}/>
```

I have tried with and without the import and always raises the error of image not found. Any idea of what can I be making wrong? I think the cause may be that I try to render the image from within the componentes folder, but I have tried many things and nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I could self solve this issue.

This question: [Astro v3 images in frontmatter not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029108/astro-v3-images-in-frontmatter-not-loading?rq=2) made me look in the direction of how was I exporting my collection, and I was calling it 'coffee' instead of coffees, so something was not working.